# Swift 5 - How to change device orientation manually on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I have the code that changes the device orientation on button tap (Even if device is not rotated).

```
override public var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

func rotate() {
    let value = nextDeviceOrientation() // My func that returns new device orientation
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
}
```

This code works for iPhones only. On iPads it has no effect.

How can I change device orientation manually on iPad?

Comment: This might be a "non-answer" but how does this behave in split screen? It doesn't look to me like size classes are involved, but there are two very major differences between a full-screen iPad app versus iPhone. (1) iPads **in full screen** will always be a regular size class no matter the orientation. (2) iPhones - at least the legacy ones with a home button rarely have "upside down" orientation (portrait with the home button on top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to check `Requires full screen`. I don't know if there is any other way.